# Getting top 'n' values from a column in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a xls sheet which revenue data for Sectors for the last 20 years. I need to do get top 3 or 5 or 10 (this no. is dynamic) revenue values for any particular sector from the xls sheet.

I had used the below pasted formula to get top 3 values but now I need the top n values where n is a dynamic number.

```
=SUM(LARGE(IF('Sector Data'!C$3:C$1000="Energy",'Sector Data'!D$3:D$1000),{1,2,3}))
```

Can someone please help get a VBA code or a xls formula to get this done.

1. Input
   Industrials 1
   Industrials 2
   Consumer Discretionary  3
   Financials  4
   Utilities   5
   Industrials 6
   Industrials 7
   Consumer Discretionary  8
   Financials  9
   Utilities   10
   Financials  11
   Financials  12
   Financials  13
   Consumer Discretionary  14
   Consumer Discretionary  15
   Utilities   16
   Utilities   17
   Consumer Discretionary  18
   Consumer Discretionary  19
   Utilities   20

   2. Output
      Top 3
      Industrials 15
      Financials  36
      Utilities   53
      Consumer Discretionary  52

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula and use the image below to match-up the ranges. You can create a cell on your spreadsheet as an input to what you would like N to be, similar to what I did here. You will need to enter the formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

```
=SUM(LARGE(IF('Sector Data'!C$3:C$1000="Energy",'Sector Data'!D$3:D$1000),ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&G3))))
```

[image]

Comment: this formula is working, thank you so much for your help. I will put it in my model file and test it. big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've been given an array formula answer. Here is a standard one.

```
=SUMIFS($D$3:$D$9999, $C$3:$C$9999, "energy", $D$3:$D$9999, ">="&AGGREGATE(14, 6, $D$3:$D$9999/($C$3:$C$9999="energy"), G3))
```

Comment: Not sure why, but when I use this formula and N is 3, it returns the top 4... I don't get it. the "k" is referencing G3, the input.

Comment: There is always a danger when using a [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) (which is what sub-function  of [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) is being used) in a *greater than* situation and that is that ties at the *k* position will produce duplicates. Sometimes this is desired behavior, sometimes not.

Comment: Ah, that's what it is! I was scratching head. Yeah, in my data-set I just threw some numbers together.